# Flet: Can't play Audio from within class

Tags: python-3.x, flet

I have a timer app I'm working on as a way to learn working with Flet.
I have a Timer class that creates a timer widget which is then added to the page. As part of each timer widget there is an ft.Audio component added to page.overlay. I've verified this is successfully added with each new timer widget.
The problem I'm having is that I cant then play this audio from within the Timer class as I get the following error:

Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'invoke_method'

Here is my Timer class:

```
import flet as ft
import threading
import time
from datetime import timedelta


class Timer(ft.UserControl):
    def __init__(self, name, duration, remove_timer_clicked):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.duration = duration
        self.delete_timer = remove_timer_clicked
        self.paused = False

    def did_mount(self):
        self.page.overlay.append(self.sound)

        self.running = True
        self.th = threading.Thread(
            target=self.update_timer,
            daemon=True)
        self.th.start()

    def will_unmount(self):
        self.running = False

    def update_timer(self):
        while self.running and self.duration:
            if self.paused:
                continue

            self.text_countdown.value = timedelta(seconds=self.duration)
            self.update()
            time.sleep(1)
            self.duration -= 1

        self.timer_end()

    def timer_end(self):
        # Updates count down text once more to set to zero
        self.text_countdown.value = timedelta(seconds=self.duration)
        self.sound.play()  # <--- Errors here
        self.update()

    def remove_timer_clicked(self, e):
        self.delete_timer(self)

    def toggle_resume_pause(self, e):
        self.paused = not self.paused
        self.button_resume.visible = not self.button_resume.visible
        self.button_pause.visible = not self.button_pause.visible
        self.update()

    def build(self):
        # Sound
        self.sound = ft.Audio(
            src="../Sounds/timer_done.mp3",
            autoplay=False
        )

        # Controls
        self.text_timer_name = ft.Text(
            value=self.name,
            text_align=ft.TextAlign.LEFT,
            size=18,
            width=335
        )

        self.text_countdown = ft.Text(
            text_align=ft.TextAlign.RIGHT,
            size=18,
            width=100
        )

        self.button_pause = ft.IconButton(
            icon=ft.icons.PAUSE_CIRCLE,
            tooltip="Pause this timer"
        )

        self.button_resume = ft.IconButton(
            icon=ft.icons.PLAY_CIRCLE,
            visible=False,
            tooltip="Resume this timer"
        )

        self.button_cancel = ft.IconButton(
            icon=ft.icons.CANCEL,
            icon_color=ft.colors.RED,
            tooltip="Remove this timer"
        )

        # Control events
        self.button_resume.on_click = self.toggle_resume_pause
        self.button_pause.on_click = self.toggle_resume_pause
        self.button_cancel.on_click = self.remove_timer_clicked

        return ft.Row(
            alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
            expand=True,
            controls=[
                self.text_timer_name,
                self.text_countdown,
                self.button_resume,
                self.button_pause,
                self.button_cancel,
            ]
        )
```

I can play sounds if they are added to main.py inside def main(page: ft.Page): but then there's no easy way to access this from the Timer class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, you need to update the `page` in the `did_mount` as seen below:

```py
def did_mount(self):
    self.page.overlay.append(self.sound)
    self.page.update()
    ...
```

The reason for this behaviour is mentioned in the flet [docs](https://flet.dev/docs/guides/python/user-controls):

> UserControl is isolated from outside layout, i.e. when update() method is called for the parent control any changes inside the UserControl are not included into the update digest. UserControl should call self.update() to push its changes to a Flet page

Comment: Ah thank you so much. I completely overlooked needing to update the page.